# webkit-transform alternative for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, webkit-transform

Is there any alternative to `-webkit-transform` CSS rules in Firefox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's called -moz-transform. Check out this article

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

Here is the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform

Comment: also `-o-transform` for opera, and `-ms-transform` for ie, and they are called _vendor prefixes_, not _alternatives_ :(

Comment: thanks but if they all do the same, why are they even differently named?

Comment: @clamp: [So from a practical perspective vendor prefixes are turning into a tool for fragmentation. From a philosophical perspective, moreover, they solve problems that just aren’t there any more.](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/03/css_vendor_pref.html)

Comment: @clamp: Yes, they all implement this spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property.