# Equivalent of -webkit-transform in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css, browser

I am able to move an image in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I have used the following code:

```
var s= $("#body").scrollTop();
$("#logo").css("-webkit-transform","translateY("+(s/3)+"px)");
```

For Firefox I have tried the following code:

```
$("#logo").css("-mozkit-transform","translateY("+(s/3)+"px)");
```

But it's not working.

What's its equivalent for Firefox?

Comment: instead of **-mozkit** write **-moz**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webkit-transform alternative for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572884/webkit-transform-alternative-for-firefox)

Answer (score 9):

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/CSS/transform

```
$("#logo").css("-moz-transform","translateY("+(s/3)+"px)");
```

And for other browsers:

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
```

Comment: The link is broken: *"Page not found"*

Answer (score 2):

The "Mozilla" version is:

```
$("#logo").css("transform","translateY("+(s/3)+"px)");
```

with no prefix.  This is, in fact, supported by current releases of all non-WebKit browsers.