# How to calculate absolute position of transformed div

Tags: css, trigonometry, webkit-transform, webkit-perspective

When you use `transform` on div, absolute positioning not working as you expected anymore, and seems like it needs to be calculated manually. For instance when you want your div to be at the bottom of container you do:

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
}
```

But if you transform this div like `-webkit-transform:rotateX(angle);` it won't be at the bottom of container. Is places somewhere in between of container depends of its size.

I create jsfiddle to illustrate this, and also show what i'm trying to achive: http://jsfiddle.net/9NHJt/

Here's the code i use:

```
<div class="container"> height: 150px;
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="height:250px"> height: 250px;
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="container"> desired result
    <div class="inner" style="bottom:-19px"></div>
</div>


.container{
    margin-top:30px;
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;
    border:1px solid black
}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(45deg);
    background:rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.8);
    border:1px dashed black;
    position:absolute;    
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0%; /* Needs to be calculated */
}
```

So, is there a way to fix this without javascript? Or how to calculate correct bottom position with js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should add a tag : 'geometry'.
First thing, remember to sine and cosine, then take a calculator :
rotation around the x assis is 45 degrees
The cos of 45 it's around 0,7, then`//value of cos for 45 degrees`
0.7*150=106 `//the height of the rectangle afther transformation`
(150-106)/2 `//the space remaining in the parent up and down the element divided by 2` 
the result is 22 and this is positive top or the negative bottom you need.

Same for the second block: (250-(0.7*250))/2 = 37.5

Remember to recalculate the value of the angle if you change it. More rounded the numbers are, more you will be accurate. Remember that calulation can be heavy for many tag.

Comment: thanks, looks great. But i don't understand how's `-webkit-perspective` value could be ignored in calculations?

Comment: I think because perspective has no effects there (in google chrome).. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/chromium-bugs/BdyVDwXelvU/Q6GWJk3LndgJ

Comment: If you need to know what's the transformation for perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029605/what-is-the-math-behind-webkit-perspective

Comment: webkit perspective could works only on chrome and safari but if you have this feature disabled, it won't works everywhere chrome://gpu/

Comment: perspective works in Firefox as well, even without `-moz-` prefix

Comment: @nukl Though -moz-transform. for firefox because of this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp
and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572884/webkit-transform-alternative-for-firefox

Anyway it works as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NHJt/3/) to check, let me know if this is what you want?

```
.inner{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(45deg);
    background:rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.8);
    border:1px dashed black;
    position:absolute;    
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /* bottom:0%; removed */
}
```

Comment: No, it's not the right solution. Second inner does not matches bottom of container. And what if i want `.inner` to be `top:0%` for example, or `.container` is `height:100%`?